# How can I prevent Spring JmsTemplate unit test from blocking when reading ActiveMQ queue?

Tags: spring, testing, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jmstemplate

How can I prevent [Spring](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/) [JmsTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html) unit test `sendAndReceivePerson()` from blocking when attempting to read a `Person` object from [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) queue `person.queue`?

The test creates a `Person` object, sends it to queue `person.queue` (this should also create the embedded broker that contains the queue), and then attempts to read the object from the same queue.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MessagingConfiguration.class})
public class PersonMessengerTest {
    @Autowired
    private PersonMessenger personMessenger;

    @Test
    public void sendAndReceivePerson() {
        final Person person = new Person();
        final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
        person.setId(id);
        person.setFirstName("Derek");
        person.setLastName("Mahar");
        personMessenger.sendPersion(person);
        final Person receivedPersion = personMessenger.receivePersion();
        assertEquals(id, receivedPersion.getId());
    }
}

public class PersonMessenger {

    private final JmsOperations jmsOperations;

    public PersonMessenger(JmsOperations jmsOperations) {
        this.jmsOperations = jmsOperations;
    }

    public void sendPersion(final Person person) {
        this.jmsOperations.convertAndSend(person);
    }

    public Person receivePersion() {
        return (Person) this.jmsOperations.receiveAndConvert();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Import({CommonConfiguration.class})
public class MessagingConfiguration {

    public static final String PERSON_QUEUE = "person.queue";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEnvironment applicationEnvironment;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        final ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMqConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                this.applicationEnvironment.getJmsBrokerUrl());
        activeMqConnectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        return activeMqConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsOperations jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(PERSON_QUEUE);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonMessenger personMessenger(JmsOperations jmsOperations) {
        return new PersonMessenger(jmsOperations);
    }

    @Bean(name = PERSON_QUEUE)
    public Queue personQueue() {
        return new ActiveMQQueue(PERSON_QUEUE);
    }
}

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class CommonConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment applicationEnvironment;

    @Bean
    public ApplicationEnvironment applicationEnvironment() {
        return new ApplicationEnvironment(this.applicationEnvironment);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
jms.brokerUrl=vm://test?async=false&broker.persistent=false&broker.useJmx=false
```

Notice that the test blocks while attempting to read the `Person` object from the queue:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.opessoftware.example.spring.messenger.PersonMessengerTest
2017-02-15 15:30:33,736|WARN|main|o.a.activemq.broker.BrokerService|49670|
    org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.checkMemorySystemUsageLimits(BrokerService.java:2142)
    Memory Usage for the Broker (1024mb) is more than the maximum available for the JVM: 955 mb - resetting to 70% of maximum available: 668 mb
2017-02-15 15:30:33,993|WARN|main|o.a.activemq.broker.BrokerService|49927|
    org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.checkMemorySystemUsageLimits(BrokerService.java:2142)
    Memory Usage for the Broker (1024mb) is more than the maximum available for the JVM: 955 mb - resetting to 70% of maximum available: 668 mb
```

Might the `receiveAndConvert()` call be creating a second embedded broker or might it be reading from a different queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A notorious problem when testing with an embedded broker.

The connection is closed between the operations and, without persistence, the data is lost.

Try wrapping the connection factory in a `CachingConnectionFactory` so the connection stays open (and hence the broker stays up).

You should really use a `CachingConnectionFactory` with a `JmsTemplate` anyway, for performance reasons, but it's particularly bad in a unit test.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I stumbled across an example on Github that wrapped the `ConnectionFactory` in a `CachingConnectionFactory` and with this change, my test passed and output only a single `BrokerService` memory warning. Now to tackle that warning...

Comment: For what it's worth, https://github.com/lex-alpha7/bank_account/blob/master/jms/src/main/java/com/ostdlabs/bank_account/jms/config/JmsSpringConfig.java is the example that I had found which demonstrates how to wrap a `ConnectionFactory` in a `CachingConnectionFactory`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Gary Russell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42261879/107158), in order to prevent each JMS operation from closing the connection and discarding the embedded broker along with the `Person` message in the queue, method `jmsConnectionFactory()` in configuration class `MessagingConfiguration` now wraps the [`ActiveMQConnectionFactory`](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.html) (which implements [`ConnectionFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html?is-external=true)) in a [`CachingConnectionFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html):

```
@Configuration
@Import({CommonConfiguration.class})
@EnableJms
public class MessagingConfiguration {

    public static final String PERSON_QUEUE = "person.queue";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEnvironment applicationEnvironment;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
        final ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMqConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                this.applicationEnvironment.getJmsBrokerUrl());
        activeMqConnectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(activeMqConnectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsOperations jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(PERSON_QUEUE);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonMessenger personMessenger(JmsOperations jmsOperations) {
        return new PersonMessenger(jmsOperations);
    }

    @Bean(name = PERSON_QUEUE)
    public Queue personQueue() {
        return new ActiveMQQueue(PERSON_QUEUE);
    }
}
```

Notice below that the test passes and outputs only a single `BrokerService` memory warning which implies that the test creates only a single embedded broker that all JMS operations use.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building spring-hibernate-jpa 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-cli) @ spring-hibernate-jpa ---
Surefire report directory: /home/derek/Projects/spring-hibernate-jpa/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.opessoftware.example.spring.messenger.PersonMessengerTest
2017-02-16 10:14:03,743|WARN|main|o.a.activemq.broker.BrokerService|1579|
    org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.checkMemorySystemUsageLimits(BrokerService.java:2142)
    Memory Usage for the Broker (1024mb) is more than the maximum available for the JVM: 955 mb - resetting to 70% of maximum available: 668 mb
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.929 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 4.190s
Finished at: Thu Feb 16 10:14:04 EST 2017
Final Memory: 8M/60M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```